# Why would local "remotes/origin/master" be out of sync with the actual remote branch?

Tags: git, git-remote, git-track, upstream-branch

I am wondering, if you do this:

```
git fetch origin master;
```

and the above command succeeds - under what circumstances would the branch `"remotes/origin/master"` ever be out of sync with the actual remote branch (on Github)?

From my observations, it appears that on occasion `"remotes/origin/master"` sees local changes that are NOT on the actual remote branch on Github. Which is very weird and I cannot explain it.

I do create branches like this locally:

```
git fetch origin master;
git branch --no-track "foo" "remotes/origin/master";  
git checkout "foo";
```

and then when I update `foo`, it seems like sometimes `remotes/origin/master` reflects the changes made to `foo`, which is mfing weird.

Comment: When you say that remotes/origin/master reflects local changes, what command output shows those changes? Do you mean `git show remotes/origin/master`? Are you using a git UI client like the Github app or Tower?

Comment: Do you know how to reproduce this?

Comment: I forget how to reproduce it, let me think about it